# Laravel $middlewareGroups exclusion for non auth routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I created a middleware group, yet I want to exclude all the non auth routes such as:

- /register
- /login
- /
- etc.

Instead of building a 'reach around' of switch cases for each non-auth route, is there an out of the box exclusion for routes on `$middlewareGroups` ?

> I need to use $middlewareGroups, not $routeMiddleware.

Thanks

Comment: Why not making two groups?

Comment: Put them at the beginning of the routes files outside of any middleware groups of create a non auth middleware and put them there. Or another option, not my fav tbh, in the middleware file return true for those routes when user is not logged in

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to exclude routes from middleware group in Laravel yet so the best thing we can do is create two separated middleware group

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll go ahead and answer my own question but I will freely change to a better more terse/Laravel answer if anyone picks up the glove, or if Taylor Otwell answers :P

Just to recap, if you build a middleware under `$middlewareGroups`, you'll apply middleware on all routes, I am using this for a role/permission base system, yet no one needs a permission for specific pages (which corrolate directly to non-Auth pages) so I was looking for an easy one line exclusion.

This is my temp. hack I did:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $nonAuth = $request->getPathInfo();

        switch ($nonAuth) {
            case "/":
                return $response;
            case "/register":
                return $response;
            case "/login":
                return $response;
            case "/logout":
                return $response;
            case "/home":
                return $response;
        }
// continue with regular Auth operations and so on and so forth
//for what you need out of this middleware.

        $userId = Auth::id();
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);

}
```